# Remove unknown string between two strings

Tags: string, bash, sed

I am looking for a solution than would allow me to remove a string starting with `s_` and ending with `='` :

I assume the following string :

```
"s_login_type='Anonymous', s_login_url='', s_login_method='GET'"
```

From this I want to keep only fields between accents, i.e.:

```
'Anonymous', '', 'GET'
```

I tried this :

```
sed "s/s_/\&/g;s/\(='\)[^\n]*\n/\1 /g"
```

but it does not remove the characters after `s_`

Is there any way to do it with sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> remove a string starting with s_ and ending with =

```
$ sed 's/s_[^=]*=//g' <<< "s_login_type='Anonymous', s_login_url='', s_login_method='GET'"
'Anonymous', '', 'GET'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use comma or equal as field separators and use every 2nd field.

```
awk -F '[,=]' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<<"$data"| paste -sd,
```

Comment: This approach will break if the quoted parts contain commas or equals